# Facebook Multi Friend Selector (Invite Friends) with Custom Url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented FB Multi Friend Selector as explained on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

```
  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request'
    }, requestCallback);
  }
```

However I want to send the custom Url to the User, since my Facebook App has some parameters at the end like below
http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME/MY_PARAMETERS

However with the above method, the user is getting the following link with the MY_PARAMETERS Omitted

I cann't see any "url" parameter in the "apprequests" method. However, this is something that Sweepstakes does successfully. They are able to pass all their parameters in the Message and I want to copy the same functionality.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the Direct URL method, as described further down the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request will point the accepting user to your canvas URL – there is nothing you can change about that.

However, if you need to pass custom data along “with” the request – there’s the `data` parameter of the dialog for that. You will get the info you put in there back, after reading the details of the request object from the API.

Comment: How to get values which is represented in "data". The callback url returns only request id and to.

Comment: And with that information you can read the whole request object from the API. This is described in the docs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/#reading

Comment: I can get details only when user accept the request in this method, but I need to get details while sending request in response